# When designing a template, how can I create a dummy text, like those in Microsoft's original templates?

Tags: ms-word

You know Microsoft's templates for Word, like the CV templates or formal letter templates etc. Those templates have dummy text like "You can edit this section bla bla..."

I'm designing a template for my friends to use. I want to add a paragraph that can be edited with a single click. How can I do that?

This is what I'm trying to say (gif): https://s8.gifyu.com/images/gif37fd08f069cff363.gif

I've tried using "MacroButton noname [Text]" but it doesn't allow using text longer than 1 line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft templates use Content Controls (on the Developer tab). Using either a Rich Text or Plain Text CC, open the Properties dialog and set the *Show as* dropdown to **None** and check the option beside **Remove content control when contents are edited**.

Now the tricky part: making the entire paragraph selected when you click on it. You can't set this with the Properties dialog. Instead you have to edit the XML, adding the line with the comment beside it:

```
<w:sdt>
    <w:sdtPr>
        <w:id w:val="1781998595"/>
        <w:placeholder>
            <w:docPart w:val="A97E97C2665C45749484CCB99C007209"/>
        </w:placeholder>
        <w:temporary/>
        <w:showingPlcHdr/><!--Add this line to the XML to make text get selected with single click-->
        <w15:appearance w15:val="hidden"/>
    </w:sdtPr>
    <w:sdtContent>
        <w:p w14:paraId="5C4F7F28" w14:textId="240370F5" w:rsidR="005B3871" w:rsidRDefault="005B3871" w:rsidP="005B3871">
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
    </w:sdtContent>
</w:sdt>
```

Here's my introduction to editing OOXML: [OOXML Hacking: An Introduction](https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2015/02/xml-hacking-an-introduction/)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I guess it's a bit too messy for me to do. But I've looked into the developer tab and found a way simpler solution. There's this "text box" option in the developer tab and it allows me to insert paragraphs. And does exactly the thing I wanted. (I was on Windows previously, now I'm using Word on a Mac. Although the developer tab in mac is a bit less allowing, the text box feature done the trick quite well.)